# Al entrar a phpmyadmin me redirecciona a otro dominio

Tags: phpmyadmin, ssh, digitalocean, xubuntu

Necesito saber como puedo configurar mi dominio para que no redireccione a otro,

Estoy ingresando a https://vamosguatemala.com/phpmyadmin

pero me redireciona a http://proyectovamos.com/phpmyadmin/

y me esta pasando no se si es alguna configuración a nivel de dominio o dns

o es configuración del servidor,

no he tocado mi archivo htaccess, así que eso no creo que sea.
o es algo a nivel de base de datos.

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: ¡Hola Carlos! Necesitaría algunos datos ¿El servidor es Linux? ¿Estás usando cPanel? ¿Estás usando algún CMS? ¿Qué contenido tienen tus archivos virtualhost? (/etc/apache2/sites-available o /etc/apache2/sites-enabled) ¿Qué contenido tiene el htaccess? ¿Te funciona el dominio a secas (https://vamosguatemala.com) o igual te redirige, probando desde chrome incógnito? Quedo atento, ¡Saludos!

Comment: Hola muchas gracias por tu respuesta,

Comment: El servidor es Ubuntu 18.04, no estoy usando cpanel, estoy usando worpdress.

Mi archivo  /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf tiene este contenido

Comment: http://prntscr.com/mqv4c4

Comment: ¿Qué contenido tiene tu archivo /etc/apache2/apache2.conf? Ahí se suele definir el directorio de phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mi problema era que ya tenia configurado la dirección **http://proyectovamos.com** en el **virtual host** adjunto el path esto aplica para ubuntu (18.04) **/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf**

Entonces la solución fue modificar al dominio que tenía en la configuración del **virtual host** donde tenía instalado mi phpmyadmin en mi caso **https://vamosguatemala.com/phpmyadmin**

Gracias a todos por su respuesta!